# How do you extract a url from a string using python?

Tags: python, string, url, extract

For example:

```
string = "This is a link http://www.google.com"
```

How could I extract 'http://www.google.com' ?

(Each link will be of the same format i.e 'http://')

Comment: You might check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499345/regular-expression-to-extract-url-from-an-html-link

Comment: None is returned when I try that solution.

Comment: If this is for a raw text file (as expressed in your question), you might check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839994/extracting-a-url-in-python

Comment: See https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There may be few ways to do this but the cleanest would be to use regex

```
>>> myString = "This is a link http://www.google.com"
>>> print re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", myString).group("url")
http://www.google.com
```

If there can be multiple links you can use something similar to below

```
>>> myString = "These are the links http://www.google.com  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839994/extracting-a-url-in-python"
>>> print re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', myString)
['http://www.google.com', 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839994/extracting-a-url-in-python']
>>>
```

Comment: This is too crude for many real-world scenarios.  It fails entirely for `ftp://` URLs and `mailto:` URLs etc, and will naïvely grab the tail part from `<a href="http://google.com/">Click here</a>` (i.e. up through "click").

Comment: @tripleee The question isn't about parsing HTML, but finding a URL in a string of text that will always be `http` format. So this works really well for that. But yes, pretty important for people to know what you're saying if they're here for parsing HTML or similar.

Comment: Only, take in mind that the above regex will match also invalid URLs. For example: `myString = "This is not a link http://not-a-valid-url"`

Answer (score 33):

There is another way how to extract URLs from text easily. You can use urlextract to do it for you, just install it via pip:

```
pip install urlextract
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
from urlextract import URLExtract

extractor = URLExtract()
urls = extractor.find_urls("Let's have URL stackoverflow.com as an example.")
print(urls) # prints: ['stackoverflow.com']
```

You can find more info on my github page: https://github.com/lipoja/URLExtract

NOTE: It downloads a list of TLDs from iana.org to keep you up to date. But if the program does not have internet access then it's not for you.

Comment: Works like a charm, and doesn't clutter the rest of my script.

Comment: Unfortunately, this fails whenever there is text (i.e., not space) attached to the beginning or end of the url. e.g. `ok/https://www.duckduckgo.com` won't catch the url in it.

Comment: This is generally a great tool. However, it doesn't properly address text adjacent to a url, such as a line break ('\n') immediately following the url. It appends that to the identified url.

Comment: Helps a lot, actually. Good stuff

Answer (score 31):

In order to find a web URL in a generic string, you can use a [regular expression (regex)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). A relatively simple one like the following should fit your use case.

```
    import re

    string = "This is a link http://www.google.com"
    #string = "This is also a URL https://www.host.domain.com:80/path/page.php?query=value&a2=v2#foo but this is not anymore"

    regex = r'('
    # Scheme (HTTP, HTTPS, FTP and SFTP):
    regex += r'(?:(https?|s?ftp):\/\/)?'
    # www:
    regex += r'(?:www\.)?'
    regex += r'('
    # Host and domain (including ccSLD):
    regex += r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9]\.)+)'
    # TLD:
    regex += r'([A-Z]{2,6})'
    # IP Address:
    regex += r'|(?:\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'
    regex += r')'
    # Port:
    regex += r'(?::(\d{1,5}))?'
    # Query path:
    regex += r'(?:(\/\S+)*)'
    regex += r')'
    
    find_urls_in_string = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
    url = find_urls_in_string.search(string)
    if url is not None and url.group(0) is not None:
        print("URL parts: " + str(url.groups()))  # OUTPUT: ('http://www.google.com', 'http', 'google.com', 'com', None, None)
        print("URL" + url.group(0).strip())       # OUTPUT: http://www.google.com
```

**NOTE:** If you are looking for more URLs in a single string, you can still use the same regex, just use [findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of [search()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search).

That said, please, **take in mind that the above regex is neither complete nor precise**. It may match some invalid URIs or not match some valid ones (e.g., `mailto:aaa@bbb.com`)!

You could make the regex more precise, for example, by ensuring that the TLD is a valid one (see the entire list of valid TLDs here: https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt):

```
    # TLD:
    regex += r'(com|net|org|eu|...)'
```

**EDITED:**

The most accurate approach to find a web URL in a generic string is probably to simply split the string and validate each sub-string using [validators](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or a similar library.

```
import validators

string = "This is a link http://www.google.com"
#string = "This is also a URL https://www.host.domain.com:80/path/page.php?query=value&a2=v2#foo but this is not anymore"

for substring in string.split(" "):
    if validators.url(substring):
        print("URL: " + substring)
    if validators.ip_address.ipv4(substring) or validators.ip_address.ipv6(substring):
        print("IP Address: " + substring)
    if validators.email(substring):
        print("Email Address: " + substring)
```

Comment: So, the regex end up being `((?:(https?|s?ftp):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?((?:(?:[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9]\.)+)([A-Z]{2,6})|(?:\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))(?::(\d{1,5}))?(?:(\/\S+)*))`. Also note the [TLD list](https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) right now also includes fun endings like `XN--VERMGENSBERATUNG-PWB`, being 24 characters long, which will not be catched by this.

Comment: Would be better to add `(?i)` to the pattern - more portable. Also, bear in mind this will match `23.084.828.566` which is not a valid IP address but is a valid float in some locales.

Comment: There's some sort of length limit to this regex e.g: `docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10FmR8upvxZcZE1q9n1o40z16mygUJklkXQ7lwGS4nlI` just matches `docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10FmR8upvxZcZE1q9n`.

Answer (score 7):

This extracts all urls with parameters, somehow all above examples haven't worked for me

```
import re

data = 'https://net2333.us3.list-some.com/subscribe/confirm?u=f3cca8a1ffdee924a6a413ae9&id=6c03fa85f8&e=6bbacccc5b'

WEB_URL_REGEX = r"""(?i)\b((?:https?:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?:com|net|org|edu|gov|mil|aero|asia|biz|cat|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|Ja|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+|\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\))+(?:\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?:com|net|org|edu|gov|mil|aero|asia|biz|cat|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|Ja|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)\b/?(?!@)))"""
re.findall(WEB_URL_REGEX, text)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can extract any URL from a string using the following patterns,

1.

```py
>>> import re
>>> string = "This is a link http://www.google.com"
>>> pattern = r'[(http://)|\w]*?[\w]*\.[-/\w]*\.\w*[(/{1})]?[#-\./\w]*[(/{1,})]?'
>>> re.search(pattern, string)
http://www.google.com

>>> TWEET = ('New Pybites article: Module of the Week - Requests-cache '
         'for Repeated API Calls - http://pybit.es/requests-cache.html '
         '#python #APIs')
>>> re.search(pattern, TWEET)
http://pybit.es/requests-cache.html

>>> tweet = ('Pybites My Reading List | 12 Rules for Life - #books '
             'that expand the mind! '
             'http://pbreadinglist.herokuapp.com/books/'
             'TvEqDAAAQBAJ#.XVOriU5z2tA.twitter'
             ' #psychology #philosophy')
>>> re.findall(pattern, TWEET)
['http://pbreadinglist.herokuapp.com/books/TvEqDAAAQBAJ#.XVOriU5z2tA.twitter']
```

to take the above pattern to the next level, we can also detect hashtags including URL the following ways

2.

```
>>> pattern = r'[(http://)|\w]*?[\w]*\.[-/\w]*\.\w*[(/{1})]?[#-\./\w]*[(/{1,})]?|#[.\w]*'
>>> re.findall(pattern, tweet)
['#books', http://pbreadinglist.herokuapp.com/books/TvEqDAAAQBAJ#.XVOriU5z2tA.twitter', '#psychology', '#philosophy']
```

3. 

The above example for taking URL and hashtags can be shortened to

```py
>>> pattern = r'((?:#|http)\S+)'
>>> re.findall(pattern, tweet)
['#books', http://pbreadinglist.herokuapp.com/books/TvEqDAAAQBAJ#.XVOriU5z2tA.twitter', '#psychology', '#philosophy']
```

4. 

The pattern below can matches two alphanumeric separated by "." as URL

```py
>>> pattern = pattern =  r'(?:http://)?\w+\.\S*[^.\s]'

>>> tweet = ('PyBites My Reading List | 12 Rules for Life - #books '
             'that expand the mind! '
             'www.google.com/telephone/wire....  '
             'http://pbreadinglist.herokuapp.com/books/'
             'TvEqDAAAQBAJ#.XVOriU5z2tA.twitter '
             "http://-www.pip.org "
             "google.com "
             "twitter.com "
             "facebook.com"
             ' #psychology #philosophy')
>>> re.findall(pattern, tweet)
['www.google.com/telephone/wire', 'http://pbreadinglist.herokuapp.com/books/TvEqDAAAQBAJ#.XVOriU5z2tA.twitter', 'www.pip.org', 'google.com', 'twitter.com', 'facebook.com']
```

You can try any complicated URL with the number 1 & 2 pattern.
To learn more about re module in python, do check this out
[REGEXES IN PYTHON](https://realpython.com/regex-python/) by Real Python.

#### Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

I've used a slight variation from @Abhijit's accepted answer.

This one uses `\S` instead of `[^\s]`, which is equivalent but more concise. It also doesn't use a named group, because there is just one and we can ommit the name for simplicity reasons:

```
import re

my_string = "This is my tweet check it out http://example.com/blah"
print(re.search(r'(https?://\S+)', my_string).group())
```

Of course, if there are multiple links to extract, just use `.findall()`:

```
print(re.findall(r'(https?://\S+)', my_string))
```