# Search and extract a URL from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to grab a url that begins with http:// or https:// from a textfile that also contains other unrelated text and transfer it to another file/list.

```
    def test():
        with open('findlink.txt') as infile, open('extractlink.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            for line in infile:
                if "https://" in line:
                    outfile.write(line[line.find("https://"): line.find("")])
            print("Done")
```

The code currently does nothing.

Edit: I see this is being negatively voted like usual, is there anything I can add here?

This is not a duplicate, please re-read carefully.

Comment: What is expected out of this `outfile.write(line[line.find("https://"): line.find("")])`?

Comment: It is expected to separate the URL from other unrelated text. Picture a file with contents like this `lorem ipsum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543095/search-and-extract-a-url-from-a-text-file dolor sit amet` There may or may not be text written after the URL so `line.find(" ")` would not be useful here.

Comment: The second part of your slice `line.find("")` this returns `0` that will completely mess up the slice. use [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: Yes @Jaba, I'm looking for the proper solution to fix that. Leaving that out won't return only the URL like needed.

Comment: Why don't you replace it with `line.find(' ')`? Or replace the entire line with `outfile.write(line.split()[0])`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting a URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839994/extracting-a-url-in-python)

Comment: Nope, it's an entirely different dilemma @mad_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you extract a url from a string using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760588/how-do-you-extract-a-url-from-a-string-using-python)

Comment: It certainly looks like these posts solve your problem, @Dansey

Comment: @JordanSinger, I've searched through them, they did not solve my problem.

Comment: Did you try them? They both seem to be answering a generalized version of your question.

Comment: @JordanSinger, I had not tried jaba's link, I will try that now! It looks like that could be the solution.

Comment: Please also reference @mad_ 's SO link, as it amounts to exactly the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760588/how-do-you-extract-a-url-from-a-string-using-python) answer. Below is this incorperated into your function.

```
def test():
        with open('findlink.txt', 'r') as infile, open('extractlink.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            for line in infile:
                try:
                    url = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", line).group("url")
                    outfile.write(url)
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
            print("Done")
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves the issue without worrying about specific TLDs or lengths!

Comment: Just a note so you can edit your solution, this returns an attribute error due to `group` if `re.search` doesn't return a url.

Comment: @Dansey Edited my answer

Comment: I know this is weeks later but does .group serve a purpose? could `?P<url>` and `.group("url")` be removed to make a simple re search? @Jab

Comment: No, re.search returns either `None` or [`re.MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) as per the docs. Read there and see your options.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re` to extract all the url.

```
In [1]: st = '''https://regex101.com/ ha the hkj adh erht  https://regex202.gov
   ...: h euy ashiu fa https://regex303.com aj feij ajj ai http://regex101.com/'''

In [2]: st
Out[2]: 'https://regex101.com/ ha the hkj adh erht  https://regex202.gov h euy ashiu fa https://regex303.com aj feij ajj ai http://regex101.com/'

In [3]: import re

In [4]: a = re.compile(r"https*://(\w+\.\w{3})/*")
In [5]: for i in a.findall(st):
   ...:     print(i)


regex101.com
regex202.gov
regex303.com
regex101.com
```

For variable tld and path:

```
st = '''https://regex101.com/ ha the hkj adh erht  https://regex202.gov h euy ashiu fa https://regex303.com aj feij ajj ai http://regex101.com/ ie fah fah http://regex101.co/ ty ahn fah jaio l http://regex101/yhes.com/'''
a = re.compile(r"https*://([\w/]+\.\w{0,3})/*")
for i in a.findall(st):
    print(i)

regex101.com
regex202.gov
regex303.com
regex101.com
regex101.co
regex101/yhes.com
```

Comment: Would this also work for URLs that have a path? All URLs being used here will contain a path and a TLD that may or may not have 3 characters.

Comment: for tld, you can use {0,3} to have no characters upto 3 characters. For path, you can include path separator in the group `/*`

Comment: Also it would help if you include some examples of url you are extracting.

Answer (score -1):

Here's why the code currently does nothing:

```
outfile.write(line[line.find("https://"): line.find("")])
```

Note that `line.find("")` is looking for the empty string. This is always going to be found at the very beginning of the string, and therefore will always return 0. Thus your list slice is 0 elements long and thus is empty.

Try changing it to `line.find(" ")` - you're looking for a space, not an empty string.

---

However, if the line contains spaces before that point, you're still going to mess up. The simplest-to-read way to do it is probably just using separate variables:

```
if "https://" in line:
    https_begin = line.find("https://")
    https_end = line[https_begin:].find(" ")  # find the next space after the url begins
    outfile.write(line[https_begin: https_end])
```

Comment: See comments. I'm not looking for a space as infile may or may not contain a space after the url.

Comment: That's not a problem though. Then the `find(' ')` would return a `-1` and you're good to go.

Comment: A possible solution using this would be to add a space to the end of findlink.txt regardless of its contents.