# regular expression in python for match url

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to use python to match url in my text file.
However, there is a special case:

```
i like pic.twitter.com/Sex8JaP5w5/a7htvq
```

In this case I would like to keep the emoji next to the url and just match the url in the middle.

Ideally, I would like to have result like this:

```
i like <url>
```

Since I am new to this, this is what I have so far.

```
pattern = re.compile("([:///a-zA-Z////\.])+(.com)+([:///a-zA-Z////\.])")
```

but the return result is something unsatisfied like this:

```
i like <url>Sex8JaP5w5/a7htvq
```

Would you please help me with this? Thank you so much

Comment: take a look at this. It might help https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611

Answer (score 0):

If looks like you are missing * or+ at the last matching group so it only matches one character. So you want `"([:///a-zA-Z////\.])+(.com)+([:///a-zA-Z////\.])*"` or `"([:///a-zA-Z////\.])+(.com)+([:///a-zA-Z////\.])+"`.

Now I don't know if this regex is simplified for your case, but it does not match all urls. For an example of that check out https://www.regextester.com/20

If you are attempting to match any url I would recommend rethinking your problem and trying to simplify down to more specific types of urls, like the example you provided.

EDIT: Also why `(.com)+`? Is there really a case where multiple ".com"s appear like .com.com.com

Also I think you have small typo and it is supposed to be `(\.com)`. But since you have `([:///a-zA-Z////\.])+` it could be reduced to `(com)`, however i think the explicit `(\.com)` makes it an easier expression to read.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using existing packages:

```
from urlextract import URLExtract
import emoji

def remove_emoji(text):
  return emoji.get_emoji_regexp().sub(r'', text)

extractor = URLExtract()
source = "i like pic.twitter.com/Sex8JaP5w5/a7htvq "
urlsWithEmojis = extractor.find_urls(source)
urls = list(map(remove_emoji, urlsWithEmojis))
print(urls)
```

output

```
['pic.twitter.com/Sex8JaP5w5/a7htvq']
```

[Try it Online!](https://repl.it/repls/LostHumiliatingOctal)

Inspired by [How do you extract a url from a string using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42255191/1248177) and [removing emojis from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50602709/1248177)